# Перебор множества приведённого к типу System.Object

Tags: c#

Есть функция которая принимает System.Object, 
которой могут передаваться Array, List или Dictionary.

Определяю тип множества и тип содержимого,
а далее столкнулся с вопросом как осуществить перебор.

```
void arrayHandler(System.Object obj){
    Type objType = obj.GetType(), elementType;
    if(objType.IsGenericType && objType.Name == "List`1"){
        elementType = objType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    // objType - тип множества
    // elementType - тип элементов

    // здесь должен быть перебор множества
}
```

Comment: Как-то дурно попахивает такая логика. Расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете изначально?

Comment: Формирование пакетов для отправки по TCP, а неопределённый тип множества и его элементов получились потому, что хочу универсальное решение.

Comment: @DarkAbsent идеального универсального решения не бывает. Ваше будет универсальным, но плохо читаемым, плохо понимаемым и подверженным ошибкам. Сделайте менее универсальное, но более понятное решение. Например, два метода, первый принимает `IEnumerable<T>`, второй `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Намёк понял, спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строготипизированный перебор вы не напишете - т.е. в коде нигде не сможете завести переменную типа elementType. Если перебор элементов как object вас устраивает, то ваш метод можно заменить на

```
using System.Collections;

void arrayHandler(System.Object obj)
{
    foreach (var element in (IEnumerable)obj)
    {
        // что-то сделать с элементом
    }
}
```

Но вообще задача довольно странная - если тип элементов заранее неизвестен - то и сделать с этими элементами особо ничего нельзя.

Comment: Сериализовать поля элементов с определёнными атрибутами в byte[] прилепить заголовок и отправить по TCP.
Я понимаю, что решение может и не очень изящное, но я только учусь и эксперементирую.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант более типизированного перебора. Пригодится, если надо перебирать большие коллекции примитивных типов, чтобы избежать упаковки.

```
void arrayHandler(System.Object obj){
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    if (objType == typeof(List<>)) {
        GetType().GetMethod("listHandler", new [] { objType }, BindingAttrs.Private | BindingAttrs.Instance).Invoke(this, new [] { obj });
    }
}

void listHandler<T>(List<T> list) {
    ....
}
```

Этот код можно упрощать дальше. К примеру, можно не реализовывать логику выбора нужного обработчика самостоятельно, а положиться на рантайм:

```
void arrayHandler(System.Object obj){
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    GetType().GetMethod("internalHandler", new [] { objType }, BindingAttrs.Private | BindingAttrs.Instance).Invoke(this, new [] { obj });
}

void internalHandler<T>(List<T> list) {
    ....
}
```

Здесь фокус в том, что мы даем всем обработчикам конкретных классов одно и то же имя - а CLR сама выберет нужный.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу же самой сериализации - попробуйте глянуть на стандартные реализации. К примеру, на [Protobuf](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119503/).

Или, если вам не важен объем трафика, можно вообще отказаться от "велосипедного" клиент-серверного взаимодействия и просто использовать WCF.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я уже написал свой BinarySerializator с блекджеком и т.д. в итоге запрос у меня выглядит так
socket.Send(Binary.Pack(new Autorize( "login" , "password" ))) при этом класс Autorize я никак к сериализации не готовлю.

Comment: ...а теперь вспоминаем, что `Socket.Send` может отправить буфер не целиком, и переписываем всю работу с сетью, отделяя сам запрос от записи байтов в сокет :)

Comment: Вы что ж так пугаете :) на msdn пишут "Если используется протокол с установлением соединения, метод Send будет выполнять блокирование до тех пор, пока не будут переданы все байты из буфера, если не истекло время тайм-аута..."

Comment: Хм, и правда...